# How to rid repeating lines in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, optimization, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have a Javascript file which adds markers to a custom Google Map, and this is the code I have:

```
var locations = [
    // Bloor Station
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.670231, -79.386821),
      url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI",
      map: map,
      icon: image
    }),
    // Castle Frank Bridge
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.674759, -79.366643),
      url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI",
      map: map,
      icon: image
    }),
// Simeon Park
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.792333395471275, -79.38898265361786),
  url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI",
  map: map,
  icon: image
}),
```

And it continues like this for each location that I have.

The problem I have is that I'm using the same map and image for each marker; moreover, there are other variables I'd like to add to all locations, without having to write the same line for each marker; as locations increases, repeating lines increase, and this could be a pain.

**Summarized, my question is: How do I make it so that I can get rid of these repeating lines?**

I've tried to run a for-loop to initialize each one after declaring the URL and position of each, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper function that creates a new Marker object, assign values to it and then push it to the locations array.

Example:

```
var locations = [];

function addMarker(lat, long, url) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    url: url,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  locations.push(marker);

}
```

And then call addMarker to add a new marker

```
addMarker(43.792333395471275, -79.38898265361786, "url");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a function?

```js
var createLocationMarker = function(lat, lng, ytId) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + ytId,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  })
};

var createLocations = function(locations) {
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = locations.length; i > 0; --i) {
    var l = locations[i];
    markers.push(createLocationMarker(l.lat, l.lng, l.yt));
  }
  return markers;
};

// static declaration, or result of an ajax request:
var locations = [
  { lat: 43.670231, lng: -79.386821, yt: 'NX7QNWEGcNI' }, // Bloor Station
  { lat: 43.674759, lng: -79.366643, yt: 'NX7QNWEGcNI' }, // Castle Frank Bridge
  { } // ...
];

var markers = createLocations(locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not used Google Maps myself but looking at that, you could do something like this:

```
var locations = [];

function addLocations(){

//NB I just copied the first value to save time, you'll need to swap the second 
//and third out for the values you need:

//Positions
var posits = [
{lat: 43.670231, lon: -79.386821},
{lat: 43.670231, lon: -79.386821},
{lat: 43.670231, lon: -79.386821}
];

//URLs
var urls = [
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI",
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI",
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7QNWEGcNI"
];

//Now, use a loop to create the locations:

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    //Place in array using values in arrays above:
    locations[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(posits[i].lat, posits[i].lon),
    url: urls[i],
    map: map,
    icon: image
    });

}

}

//Invoke function when desired
addLocations();
```

If you keep the arrays for posits/urls in the function they will be removed from memory after use, if you need to refer to them again you could make them global but unless you have to, I wouldn't - I presume the data could be referenced afterward from the objects in the locations array anyway.

Also - there's no reason why the URLs could not be inside the object which stores the lat/long data, another answer does something like this, I wrote it out for readability but it's really personal choice.